# How to select multiple columns in a select sub-query in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a row of another table as a sub-query of the SELECT query.

```
SELECT g.ip, g.version, t.testid, t.status, m.rundate, t.runid , (select * from B where runid=t.runid and testid=t.testid) 
  FROM Tests t, Master m, Env g
        WHERE t.runid=m.runid
        AND t.runid=g.runid
        AND g.version = "1.2.3"
        AND t.testid like "%test_name%" 
        AND g.ip in ("198.18.111.222")
        order by m.rundate desc;
```

How can this be achieved?
Thanks!

Comment: You can try SQL joins for this type of query .

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT g.ip, g.version, t.testid, t.status, m.rundate, t.runid , c.* from B c 
Join Tests t on t.runid =t.testid 
join Master m on t.runid=m.runid 
join Env g on t.runid=g.runid 
WHERE g.version = "1.2.3" AND t.testid like "%test_name%" 
AND g.ip in ("198.18.111.222")
order by m.rundate desc;
```

at line 2 if there is any id in B table which matches with the id in Tests
replace t.runid = t.testid (suppose if you have runid in B table which relates to test table testid then replace with c.runid = t.testid)to the requirement in which the B table and tests table are satisfying the scenario of matching ID's(PK and FK).